# How to handle retain count for controllers saved in AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, retaincount

MyAppDelegate is doing some background stuff and needs to refresh several views during this time, so I am saving a reference to each controller that gets created.

```
@interface MyAppDelegate : NSObject <UIApplicationDelegate> {
    SomethingController *currentSomethingController;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) SomethingController *currentSomethingController;
```

This is done to open the controller:

```
- (void)openSomethingController {
    MyAppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.currentSomethingController = [[SomethingController alloc] init];
    [self presentModalViewController:app.currentSomethingController animated:NO];
}
```

And this is called inside the controller to close it:

```
- (void)dismissSelf
{
    MyAppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [app.currentSomethingController release];
    app.currentSomethingController = nil;
[self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

In MyAppDelegate the controllers is sending messages to the controller:

```
- (void)longRunningBackgroundTask {
    [currentSomethingController performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(updateData) withObject:nil waitUntilDone:YES];
}
```

If I do Product->Analyse I get "potential leak" and "incorrect decrement" warnings. What would be the right way to do this or assuming my approach is okay, how do I tell the analysis tool to ignore those lines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though your code seems fine, why are you doing that? It can lead to confusion to an outsider reading your code, also you should not explicitly call release on a property, you should just let the memory managment occur in the property itself, so rewrite your code like

```
- (void)openSomethingController {
    MyAppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
     SomethingController *controller=[[SomethingController alloc] init];
    app.currentSomethingController = controller;
    [controller release];
    [self presentModalViewController:app.currentSomethingController animated:NO];
}
```

and then

```
- (void)dismissSelf
{
    MyAppDelegate * app = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    app.currentSomethingController = nil;
   [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:NO];
}
```

Comment: I thought the property is only retaining, not releasing the object, so the confusing was not only the outside reader's. Thank you for pointing out the right way to do it!